# Receive new value by two Class constructors

Tags: java, constructor

I have Two Class:

```
public class ClassA {

String NewName;

public ClassA() {
    System.out.println("new name in A constructor: " + NewName);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassA aM = new ClassA();
    aM.action();
    aM.displayNewName();
}

public void displayNewName() {
    System.out.println("new name in display method:" + getNewName());
}

public void action() {
    ClassB bA = new ClassB();
    System.out.println("new name in Action:" + getNewName());
}

public String getNewName() {
    return NewName;
}

public void setNewName(String newN) {
    NewName = newN;
    System.out.println("new name in A Set Method: " + getNewName());
}
}
```

And:

```
public class ClassB {

String newName = "jack";
ClassA a;

public ClassB(){
    a.setNewName(newName);
}
}
```

I can not receive `jack` value on my `ClassA` methods (like `displayNewName()` and `action` methods.

**Update**

```
    public class ClassB {

String newName = "jack";
ClassA a = new ClassA();

public ClassB(){
    a.setNewName(newName);
}
}
```

Output:

```
new name in A constructor: null
new name in A constructor: null
new name in A Set Method: jack
new name in Action:null
new name in display method:null
```

Comment: *"I can not receive"* << please detail (error, exception?)

Comment: @m0skit0 i receive `nullPointerException` or `Null` value occasionally

Comment: No offense meant: sincerely, you should get a good Java book and start reading. This is no place to learn how to program, but to ask specific questions. Your question is ever changing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

variable `a` is not initialized. it will throw `nullpointerexception`. 
you need to initialize it in constructor by adding this line : `a = new ClassA()`;

**Edit1:**

from what I understood, you need to do this:

```
public class ClassB {

String newName = "jack";

public ClassB(ClassA a){
    a.setNewName(newName);
}
}
```

and then in ClassB, modify action()

```
public void action() {
    ClassB bA = new ClassB(this);
    System.out.println("new name in Action:" + getNewName());
}
```

Comment: Well, Now i received this: `new name in A constructor: null
new name in A constructor: null
new name in A Set Method: jack
new name in Action:null
new name in display method:null`

Comment: @Sajjad check it again

Comment: where was my mistake?!

Comment: @Sajjad there were 2 objects of same ClassA, you were assigning to one but accessing from the other.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `ClassB`

```
public class ClassB {

String newName = "jack";
ClassA a=new ClassA();  // Initialize a

public ClassB(){
    a.setNewName(newName);
}
}
```

Edit:

```
public void action() {
        ClassB bA = new ClassB();
        System.out.println("new name in Action:" + bA.newName);
    }
```

Comment: I want to see `jack` in my `action()` or `display()` method

Comment: @Sajjad check my edited `Action()`. In this way you can have it

Answer (score 1):

a is not initialized. Try a=new ClassA(); in the constructor